# Regex to get schema and tables names in from, left join and inner join clauses

Tags: regex

I need to get schema and table names from many sql files, but I have no idea how do it.

The files contains from, left join, inner join clauses.

The pattern of schema.table is `DB2ABC.TABLE_NAME`.

Schema always start with DB2 and then 3 letters. Table name don't have a default pattern.

I've tried following on the RegExr

```
/(DB2[\w\.\w])\w+/g
```

Over this sql:

```
select
*
from DB2ABC.TABLE_1 a
left join DB2BCD.TABLE_2 b ON a.id = b.id
inner join DB2CDE.TABLE_3_AUX c ON a.id = c.id
;
```

But it's only got DB2ABC, DB2BCD, DB2CDE. I need `DB2ABC.TABLE_1`, `DB2BCD.TABLE_2`, `DB2CDE.TABLE_3_AUX`.

How can i do it?

Comment: You need `\bDB2\w+\.\w+`, see https://regex101.com/r/LkBvi2/1

Comment: This problem, parsing arbitrary SQL statement text, cannot be solved with a single regular expression. It is a huge, *huge* undertaking.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
DB2\w+\.\w+
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/yzmbc4/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  DB2                      'DB2'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
```